# jQuery keyboard navigation – go back and forward a page with left and right

Tags: jquery, keyboard-events

I'd like the user to be able to load the next or previous page when they press left or right on the keyboard. The next and previous links for each page are contained within two buttons.

The html...

```
<a href="/page-link-prev" class="prev button">&lt; Prev</a>
<a href="/page-link-next" class="next button">Next &gt;</a>
```

Some jquery I found that registers the right key presses, but doesn't change the url obviously, it just shows an alert.

```
$(function() {
  $(document).keyup(function(e) {
    switch(e.keyCode) {
      case 37 : alert('You pressed Left'); break;
      case 39 : alert('You pressed Right'); break;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Keyboard Navigation to load pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768738/keyboard-navigation-to-load-pages)

Comment: I have complied a whole article on it.[ ***Feel free to check out...***](http://crazylearner.com/jquery-keyboard-navigation/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**`.load()`**](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to load from a URL to a portion of the page.

> **.load( url, [data,] [complete(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest)] )**
>
> Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched
>   element.

I'm assuming you have a specific `div` you want to refresh w page contents, and you don't want to refresh the entire page

```
$(function() {
  $(document).keyup(function(e) {
    switch(e.keyCode) {
      case 37 : $('#page').load($(".prev").attr("href")); break;
      case 39 : $('#page').load($(".next").attr("href")); break;
    }
  });
});
```

Or, if you want to refresh the entire page you can use [**`window.location`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.location)

> Whenever a property of the location object is modified, a document
>   will be loaded using the URL as if **window.location.assign()** had been
>   called with the modified URL.

```
$(function() {
  $(document).keyup(function(e) {
    switch(e.keyCode) {
      case 37 : window.location = $('.prev').attr('href'); break;
      case 39 : window.location = $('.next').attr('href'); break;
    }
  });
});
```

You can replace `#page`with the element you are refreshing.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use the location property of the window object like this:

```
$(function() {
   $(document).keyup(function(e) {
    switch(e.keyCode) {
      case 37 :
        window.location="/page-link-prev";
      break;
      case 37 :
        window.location="/page-link-next";
      break;
    }
  });
});
```

Or you can trigger the click event on the jQuery object of your anchor.

Comment: Than give it a "usefull answer" flag ;)