# Logging the usage of js keyboard navigation with AJAX calls from JS code or something

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, logging

I started to add [this keyboard navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12682157/keyboard-navigation-with-arrow-keys-next-and-back-for-changing-filenames) for my next/back pages, and wanted to log the usage of it..  I mean how much people use it, and from what pages and so..  and I've been told that it could be done with AJAX calls from JS code or something..

Any suggestions how to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Google Analytics and some scripting to do your event tracking.  More information on how to do event tracking here:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide